# fail to get json object in javascript from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to pass json string to javascript from php, so at first i did

```
<div id="picker" data-dates=\''.json_encode(unserialize($a->available_datetime)).'\'></div>
```

and then, i try to grab it in jquery

```
if($("#picker").length){
    available = $("#picker").attr("data-dates");
}
```

However, it seems it then fail to loop through the object to get `key` and `val`

```
$.each(available,function(key,val)
{}
```

It keep getting error of

> var length = !!obj && "length" in obj && obj.length,

Tried for several hours now, cant find a solution to solve. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: Where is your Json String? You are doing json_encode() - so obviously there is no Json from PHP?

Comment: Can you check the developer tools and check what this attribute actually holds and post it to us.

Comment: @Gerfried, there is json from php

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi, <div id="picker" data-dates='{"all":[]}'> is one of the json string output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$("#picker").data("dates")` it will get the data stored in the attribute `data-dates` and convert it to JSON, assuming you have a JSON string in that attribute.

Then use:

```
 for (var i in available) {
      //do something with available[i]
 }
```

check example: https://jsfiddle.net/fud6sfjo/

Comment: when doing this way, it turn out to be  Object { all=[0]} after convert to json and did console.log(available)

Comment: the problem is not solved, as by doing this, when do console.log(available.length) return "undefined "

Comment: thanks, think i made a mistake, i just discovered it. Thanks